# Passing csrftoken with python Requests use input type hidden

Tags: python, cookies

I have python code like this

```
s=requests.Session()
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

URL = 'http://test.dev/api/login'

s.get(URL)
csrftoken = s.cookies['csrf']
print csrftoken
login_data = dict(username='test', password='testtest', _token=csrftoken)
ra=s.post(URL, data=login_data, headers = headers)
print ra.request.headers
```

But I don't want to find the csrftoken = s.cookies['csrf'] from cookie,
So how can I fine it with

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrf">
```

and is it need to put header Referer=URL when request with csrftoken or it just some site?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try using BeautifulSoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s=requests.Session()
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

URL = 'http://test.dev/api/login'
s.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(URL).text)
csrf = soup.find(name="csrf")
```

This will extract the hidden input that holds the `csrf_token` Since I can't see where and how the value of the token is stored this is as far as I can take you.

Comment: Thank you very much. first I trying you code but it not get the value. so I searching for bs4 and use csrf = soup.find("input", value=True)["value"] and it got the value.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Moe Jan.

First I trying you code but it did not get the value.

```
csrf = soup.find(name="csrf")
```

So I searching for bs4 and use

```
 csrf = soup.find("input", value=True)["value"]
```

and it got the value.

My form is like

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="http://test.dev/api/login" method="POST">
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="8z0dMEpVq8jH0VY5zgh8xFhcrQaurz">
</input>
</form>
```